# Angular Cli Installation problem . prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I'm new to angular. While downloading it with npm i -g @angular/cli I am getting error of fulfillment-telephony-nodejs;

The npm -v command is showing this error

```
'CALL "node" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

I installed the 12. version of node. I have everything in administration mode.

```
'''
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

npm ERR! file C:\Users\Aniket Bhunia\Desktop\fulfillment-telephony-nodejs;
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Aniket Bhunia\Desktop\fulfillment-telephony-nodejs;
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Users\Aniket Bhunia\Desktop\fulfillment-telephony-nodejs;
npm ERR! @angular/cli@8.2.0 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Users\Aniket Bhunia\Desktop\fulfillment-telephony-nodejs; ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@8.2.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
'''
```

Comment: Make sure you select to install npm will installing nodejs, also try to clear npm cach `npm cache clean`

Comment: I have tried clearing npm cache and npm update. But this problem still remains.

Comment: How to select install npm?

Comment: try to downgrade nodejs latest stable version 10.16.2 LTS

Comment: I have done that too. The same problem occurs.

Comment: I have checked the paths too. They are all there. But this fulfillment-telephony nodejs is creating problem.

Comment: Why this file `C:\Users\Aniket Bhunia\Desktop\fulfillment-telephony-nodejs` created on desktop? try to delete it